# Building a new version of an Dynamic Library In C++ on a linux OS, brings up the oldest one

Tags: c++, linux, build, compilation

I have this c++ application that works with a DLL that I created. It's working great, but when I trying to edit something into my DLL and I'm building it, then I build my application. The result is that I somehow getting an oldest addition to my DLL without the new changes. How can this be possible? I'm cleaning the project DLL before building it.
What am I missing?

Comment: Check the project configuration and target location of the produced DLL and make sure you are coping to the app path also. BTW, in Linux it's a .so rather DLL. If you're keeping it in a system wide library path, make sure to do `ldconfig`

Comment: You did install the shared library to the correct location? You made the correct symbolic links? You restarted your application? Have you perhaps changed the version number or the file name of the "new" shared library? Perhaps if you relink the application?

Comment: I copied the .so to another place, build it again, put the new path to my application build it too, after cleaning it. and now it's working. Not sure what was the problem to begin with.